# login authentication not writing data in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, mlab

I have a problem regarding my login/authentication node script. I believe the problem is that I don't even write in the mongodb, because when I check the db on mlab there's no data.

This is the app.js script in which the problem should be. The problem cannot be in signup.js or login.js as there would be an error alert.

Any help appreciated!

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var favicon = require("static-favicon");
var logger = require("morgan");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var helmet = require("helmet");    
var dbConfig = require("./db");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url);

var app = express();

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.use(helmet());
app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

//configuring passport
var passport = require("passport");
var expressSession = require("express-session");
app.use(expressSession({secret: "secretKey"}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

var flash = require("connect-flash");
app.use(flash());

var initPassport = require("./passport/init");
initPassport(passport);

var routes = require("./routes/index")(passport);
app.use("/", routes);

app.use(function(req,res,next) {
  var err = new Error("Error Not found");
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

if(app.get("env") === "development") {
  app.use(function(err,req,res,next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render("error", {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: please show your login and signup route as well, as nothing seems to be wrong inthe app.js

Comment: hey, i could strike down the problem that "req.body" in express is not defined. At the moment I'm figuring out how to fix it but at least i got an actual error.

Comment: so you are getting, `req.body` as `undefined`? is this your problem?

Comment: yeah, probably should open another post

Comment: Are you passing json in your POST request?? if not then you must pass json only. and make sure your request in JSON